# Roslyn AddDocument to a project and Save this change to real solution file

Tags: c#, roslyn

This should add a document.

```
    public static void AddDoc()
    {
        var msBuild = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();

        var sln = msBuild.OpenSolutionAsync
            (@"D:\PanNiebieski\Documents\Visual Studio 14\Projects\WebApplication1"
            + @"\WebApplication1.sln").Result;

        foreach (var p in sln.Projects)
        {
            p.AddDocument(Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt", "test");

            var ok = msBuild.TryApplyChanges(sln);

            Console.WriteLine(p.Name + ":" + ok);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Method "TryApplyChanges" returns true so that means document was added.
Then again when I check solution nothing like that exist.
I have the same problem with adding references to a project.

The question is how I can save change like adding a document to a real project. Do I miss something. Many question in StackOverflow about adding  references to a project said that this simply doesn't work. Does method "AddDocument" also does nothing?

This method says this action is supported. I am confused.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you add a .cs file?  Looking at http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Desktop/Workspace/MSBuild/MSBuildWorkspace.cs,1285b31dd95f5004, I see some extension stuff there. (Also, this code has changed since the VS2015 Preview)

Comment: Doesn't work after updating packages from beta1 to beta2. "cs" file extension didn't do anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Roslyn's entire workspace & syntax APIs are immutable.

`p.AddDocument` creates a new `Project` and `Solution` (which is returned in the `Project` property of the returned `Document`), which you're ignoring.

Comment: Thanks. If I  can create snippet based on your answer then you win.

Answer (score 6):

This one should do the thing:

```
IWorkspace workspace = Workspace.LoadSolution(@"..\RoslynTest.sln");
var originalSolution = workspace.CurrentSolution;
var project = originalSolution.GetProject(originalSolution.ProjectIds.First());
IDocument doc = project.AddDocument("index.html", "<html></html>");
workspace.ApplyChanges(originalSolution, doc.Project.Solution);
```

source:
http://www.wenda.io/questions/982766/roslyn-add-a-document-to-a-project.html

UPDATE: it is not applicable anymore.

Comment: That was also helpful. The thing that you can get from Document object new project and new solution wasn't so obvious.

Comment: Note that this answer, and the link in the answer uses the no-longer-used interfaces `IWorkspace` and `IDocument` rather than the currently used `Workspace` and `Document`